# Grails App Missing GORM Methods?

Tags: hibernate, maven, grails, grails-orm

My team has been trying to upgrade our existing Grails app from 1.3.7 to 2.1.0. After a lot of frustrations, including updating our entire test suite, everything is running as expected on our local machines. However, once we put the app on our WAS 8 WebSphere server we run into a strange error when trying to access any of our main pages. Below is an example

```
No signature of method: com.app.Product.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure). Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.app.Product.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
....
```

Further down in the stack trace is this:

```
....
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... 47 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.app.Product.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
at com.app.controllers.DomainTablesController$_closure2.doCall(DomainTablesController.groovy:26)
... 47 more
```

I added some test code to check and `findAll()`, `getAll()`, and `list()` methods all throw the same error. I'm no Grails guru, but it looks like the standard GORM methods are missing. We use Maven to package the Grails WAR inside an EAR which is installed on the server. Here is the dependencies section of our pom.xml. It is only slightly modified from the clean version created using the `grails create-pom` command.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <exclusions>                
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>            
        </exclusions>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>                    

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>                    

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Bit more info about the project: We are hanging grails on an existing DB2 legacy database. Checking the WAR Maven generates, I can see that the `grails-datastore-gorm` and `grails-hibernate` JARS exist. So I'm lost as to why the basic GORM methods are not accessible in the app.

Any insight or suggestions anyone has would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

After adding the hibernate and grails-hibernate plugin dependencies, a new error occurs when accessing the login page. Without the grails-hibernate plugin, login page shows fine and logging in works as expected. New error is:

```
Error Page Exception: 
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet: 
Error Stack: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' for connect URL 
...
...
...
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver 
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:453) 
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437) 
 ... 35 more
```

The drivers are already set up on the server we are deploying to, and the 1.3.7 version had no issue finding the db2 drivers or connecting to the database. Thoughts?

Comment: First thing I would try is to pack a WAR using grails war instead of Maven and see if that works. If yes, the problem lays in Maven build..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think hibernate was moved to a separate dependency since 2.0.*, so you might need to add the below `dependencies` :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
  <artifactId>grails-hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>${grails.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>${grails.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

and remove this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

`groovy-all` is packaged in Grails by default but I am not sure if the version is 1.8.6. If you want to explicitly use 1.8.6 then `exclude` `groovy-all` from `grails-dependencies` and then add the above dependency.

**Good to have:-**

- If possible you can try upgrading to the most recent version of stable release of Grails 2.3.7, since you are already going through the process of upgrade.
- I know this will a steep rock to climb with management. Switch to [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). ;)

Comment: Added the Hibernate dependency and removed the Groovy one. Same error occurs after building EAR and installing on server. But its not more broken, so that;s better than other things I've tried.

Our plan was to do a quick upgrade to 2.1.0, then go to the latest version after we have that working. I've wanted to look into Gradle since I keep hearing its much better for dependency management. Unfortunately I work for a large corporation so getting any kind of change like that approved tends to take a awhile.

Comment: You would need `hibernate` grails plugin as well. Added to answer. Make sure a `mvn clean install -DappDeploy` (clean install deploy) is used to pick up new dependencies. As far as upgrade goes, I would rather try to make the app work in 2.3.7 by creating a brand new app in 2.3.7 and try to port all classes/configs from older project to the new app and making sure all tests pass and app works as expected.

Comment: Adding the grails-hibernate plugin caused a new error, this time complaining about missing db2 drivers before getting to the login page. Edited question with stacktrace and some more info.

Comment: Mulligan! I hadn't added the -DappDeploy flag. Rebuilt with that and it seems like it working. Thanks a ton!